# Use DaoAuthenticationProvider OR LdapAuthenticationProvider based on configuration in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I have successfully implemented Spring boot applications with exclusively DaoAuthentication and with exclusively LdapAuthentication before. Both applications habe a custom login page, authenticate against database or LDAP respectively and generate a JWT.

In a new project, I now need to be able to switch between those two AuthenticationProvidors based on user configuration (that is stored in database). In both cases, I call AuthenticationManager.authenticate with a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and in both cases I generate a JWT.

I still haven't found a good way to authenticate with a specific provider based on configuration and it gives me headaches.

Could anyone give me a hint to the right direction or (even better) show an example?

Thank you!